# Parse european string date to Django DateField

Tags: django, date, parsing

I am using `USE_L10N = True` in my app settings. As I understood, this setting let Django adapt date format according to the user current locale.

So in the admin, my model that contains a DateField is correctly represented in the form with the format "%d/%m/%Y".

The problem I have is when I want to create a new object from my code. I have a CSVParse custom function parsing a CSV file and creating objects. One of the column in the CSV has the same format as above ("17/12/2015" for instance). I tried to parse the date with the line below but it returns "None". In the documentation of date_parse, I can see that it means a wrong format.

```
from django.utils import dateparse

date_csv = "18/12/2014"
date = dateparse.parse_date(date_csv)
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django [dateparse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/utils/dateparse/#parse_date) uses `date_re` (regex) for `parse_date` and `date_re` format is `year-month-day`

```
date_re = re.compile(
    r'(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{1,2})-(?P<day>\d{1,2})$'
)
```

The input you are giving is having format `day/month/year` hence you are getting `None` as result.

Comment: Hm ok, I thought it would adapt according to the current locale. But this part is apparently static... I will use the solution from demonno by now. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime)

```
import time

date_csv = "18/12/2014"
date = time.strptime(date_csv, "%d/%m/%Y")
```